# What to expect when processing TCP data

Tags: c++, tcp, recv

I am using a POSIX OS (vxWorks) and want to understand how to process TCP data. I understand in UDP everything is really up to you and TCP is a lot more managed underneath.

Suppose a remote socket I am connected to promises to send me JSON data. The documentation simply says, once established, we will send you JSON data.

Using the function `recv` on the TCP socket, and assuming I give it a buffer of an extreme size, should I expect that I would always get perfectly assembled JSON data even though the message may be sent in multiple chunks on the interface layer, or do I need to essentially parse each buffer of data I received until I think I have a fully formed JSON message?

Comment: You need to concatenate all the data, then parse it as JSON once you've received everything.

Comment: Correct. You could get many more or many fewer bytes than you expect. The easiest is often to use a *"Framing Protocol"* where you send, say a 4-byte integer in network endianness as the first 4 bytes of every message. Then you keep trying to read whatever is still outstanding until you have it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP has no idea about application messages. You need to implement the protocol layered on top of TCP to find message boundaries, if your protocol has one.

Comment: So if I said, hey `send` this JSON data that's not even that big (1kb) could `recv` potentially return that to me in many different chunks? Could it even have the end of one JSON object and beginning of another within the same message?

Comment: @ony_pox232 yes, and yes.  TCP is a byte stream, it has no concept of messages, and as such each message being sent must be *framed* in such a way that the receiver knows where one message ends and the next begins.  For instance, by sending the JSON's length before sending the JSON itself. Or sending a terminating delimiter after the JSON that will never appear in the JSON itself. Every protocol that runs on top of TCP works this way.

Comment: @ony_pox232 Yes. A TCP stream is just a ordered stream of bytes and `recv` just returns to you the bytes that are currently available in the stream. So, you may get just a single byte (or none at all) every time you call `recv` or you may get a few gigabytes representing thousands of individual messages. It's just a byte stream - it's up to you to parse and make sense of that stream (in whatever chunk sizes you get it).

Comment: The answer to the first question is yes. The answer to the second question is that TCP doesn't prevent this from happening, but the application protocol layered on top of it might. For example, it may specify that only one JSON object is sent and that another one isn't sent until the first one is acknowledged. You have to actually implement the particular protocol layered on top of TCP according to its specification.